# How to get rows for n distinct values of a column

Tags: sql, db2, distinct

I need to get rows for n distinct invoice numbers.

I have SELECT query that gives me results from the table:

```
SELECT A.INVOICE_NUMBER, A.INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER, B.FILE_NUMBER 
FROM TABLE1 AS A, TABLE2 AS B 
WHERE A.INVOICE_NUMBER = B.INVOICE_NUMBER 
      AND A.INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER = B.INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER
```

So I get this as a result of my query:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| INVOICE_NUMBER | INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER | FILE_NUMBER |
------------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          1         | P4324324525 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          2         | P4565674574 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          3         | V4324552557 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          4         | V4324552525 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|2222222222-2    |          1         | S4563636574 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|3333333333-3    |          1         | Q4324325675 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|3333333333-3    |          2         | Q4565674574 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|4444444444-4    |          1         | F4326364366 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|4444444444-4    |          2         | F4565636323 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|4444444444-4    |          3         | F4398798588 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|4444444444-4    |          4         | F4565865888 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

But what I need is, for example, to get result for only three distinct invoice numbers, so my query should give this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| INVOICE_NUMBER | INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER | FILE_NUMBER |
------------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          1         | P4324324525 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          2         | P4565674574 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          3         | V4324552557 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1111111111-1    |          4         | V4324552525 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|2222222222-2    |          1         | S4563636574 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|3333333333-3    |          1         | Q4324325675 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|3333333333-3    |          2         | Q4565674574 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

How I could achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of `JOIN`?

In any case, one way to solve your problem uses `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER, FILE_NUMBER
FROM (SELECT A.INVOICE_NUMBER, A.INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER, B.FILE_NUMBER,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.INVOICE_NUMBER) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE1 A JOIN
           TABLE2 B 
           ON A.INVOICE_NUMBER = B.INVOICE_NUMBER AND 
              A.INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER = B.INVOICE_SEQ_NUMBER
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: I am having performance issues with this query, can you please take a look? Created new thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877467/db2-performance-issue-while-executing-select-query